# If $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ with $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)^*$, is $u \in H^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, laplacian, weak-derivatives

Suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded smooth domain. If $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ is such that $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)^* \subset H^1(\Omega)^*$, does it follow that $u \in H^2(\Omega)$?

By $-\Delta u$ I mean the weak Laplacian, which usually is defined as the object in $H^1(\Omega)^*$ such that
$$\langle -\Delta u , v \rangle = \int_\Omega \nabla u \nabla v$$ for every $v \in H^1(\Omega)$.

**I cannot identify $L^2(\Omega)$ and $L^2(\Omega)^*$, for certain reasons.** If I could do so, then the answer is immediate from elliptic regularity.

Comment: Can you write down explicitly what you mean by $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)^*$?

Comment: @ArcticChar First we have $-\Delta u \in (H^1)^*$ meaning that $\langle -\Delta u, v \rangle = \int_\Omega \nabla u \nabla v$ for every $v \in H^1$. But we know more, and that is that the left hand side of this formula makes sense for $v \in L^2(\Omega)$ too. That's what i mean, is it clear?

Comment: Can I rephrase it as: the elements $\ell \in (H^1)^*$ defined by $\ell (v) = \int \nabla u\cdot\nabla  v$ extends to an element $\tilde \ell$ in $(L^2)^*$?

Comment: . Yes .  . Exactly

Comment: Um.... Then isn't that just elliptic regularity? If $\ell$ extends to elements in $L^2(\Omega)$, then $\int_\Omega \nabla u\cdot \nabla v = \ell(v) = \int_\Omega v g$ for some $g\in L^2$. I guess I don't understand why you cannot use $L^2 \cong (L^2)^*$....

Comment: Strictly speaking it should be $\int \nabla u \nabla v = l(v) = \int_\Omega vR(l)$ where $R\colon (L^2)^* \to L^2$ is the Riesz map. So elliptic regularity gives $-\Delta u = R(l)$ with $u \in H^2$...??? What do you think?

Comment: Yes, exactly. ${}{}$