# Do $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ and $\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega)$ imply $u\in H^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

> Suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded open domain in $\mathbb R^n$ with regular boundary. If $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ and $-\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega)$, do we have $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ for sure?

Here we say $\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega)$ by meaning $u$ has weak derivatives $\partial_{x_i}^2 u$ for $i=1,\cdots,n$ and
$$
\Delta u:=\sum_{i=1}^n \partial_{x_i}^2u\in L^2(\Omega).
$$
There is a related [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3773735/if-u-in-h1-omega-with-delta-u-in-l2-omega-is-u-in-h2-omega), and some comments refer to Theorem 8.12 in Gilbarg and Trudinger's [book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-61798-0). I think their theorems are essentially proving the following result:

> Suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded open domain in $\mathbb R^n$ with regular boundary. If $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $-\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega)$, then $u\in H^2(\Omega)$.

The proof can be accomplished using the Lax-Milgram theorem and the regularity of the weak solution. However, the original problem does not assume $u$ has zero trace, and this result cannot be directly applied.

In Helffer's [Spectral Theory and Its Applications](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/spectral-theory-and-its-applications/08793F97E428061CAEFBD6F78EC2D66F), Equation (4.4.5) at Page 38 defines the space
$$
W(\Omega) = \{u\in H^1(\Omega):-\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega)\}
$$
and claims that there is NO $W(\Omega)\subset H^2(\Omega)$. It seems that the answer to the original problem is negative, but I am not sure where to find a counterexample. Any helpful comments or answers are appreciated.

Comment: @MaoWao Not true. Boundary regularity or convexity of $\Omega$ is necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  The main problem is the regularity of the data on the boundary.  Suppose for the sake of being concrete that $\partial \Omega$ is smooth.  Then pick boundary data $g \in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega) \backslash H^1(\partial \Omega)$.  From weak well-posedness theory there exists a unique $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ such that $u \vert_{\partial \Omega} = g$ in the trace sense and $-\Delta u =0$ in $\Omega$.  The latter requires that $u \in C^\infty(\Omega)$, and yet the regularity of $u$ on the boundary is locked into place by that of $g$.  Now, if we had that $u \in H^2(\Omega)$ then trace theory would require that $u\vert_{\partial \Omega} \in H^{3/2}(\partial \Omega) \subset H^1(\partial \Omega)$, which is impossible by the choice of $g$.  Thus, while $u$ is smooth in $\Omega$, its second derivatives are not square integrable up to the boundary.

Answer (score 3):

For a specific example consider the three-quarter disc, $\Omega=\{(r, \theta):0 < r < 1, 0 < \theta < \frac{3 \pi}{2}\}$ and
$$u(r, \theta) = r^{\alpha} \sin(\alpha\theta)$$
with $\alpha = \frac{2}{3}$. It holds that $\Delta u = 0$ which is clearly $L^2$, but if you check, you find that $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ and $u\not\in H^2(\Omega)$.

I think this and a whole family of functions like it are great examples as they arise as 'singular' solutions to the Poisson problem. I used a similar example recently to show how irregularities arise from the corners of an otherwise smooth domain. You should checkout this [fantastic book](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611972030?mobileUi=0&) on irregularties of elliptic problems by Grisvard.

**Edit:**

As mentioned by @Glitch, the above example does not have a regular boundary, but does have regular BCs. However, it is quite simple to construct the reverse.

Consider the unit disc $D = \{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}$ and in polar coordinates $(0 \le \theta < 2\pi)$
$$u(r, \theta) = r^{\frac12}\sin(\frac12 \theta).$$
Again, this has $u\in H^1(D)$ but $u\not\in H^2(D)$.

Indeed, it is the solution to the Laplace problem
\begin{alignat}{2}
-\Delta u =&\, 0 \quad &&\textrm{in }D, \\
u =& \sin(\frac12 \theta) \quad &&\textrm{on }\partial D.
\end{alignat}
Clearly this problem is posed in a smooth domain, but with irregular boundary data.

Comment: This is indeed a great example to keep in mind, and I second the reference to Grisvard, which is fantastic.  However, the boundary is merely Lipschitz, and the post asks for what happens when the boundary is "regular."  This is often synonymous with smooth.

Comment: Hmmm... good point. I think it is still interesting enough to leave it here though despite not exactly answering the question.

Comment: Definitely don't delete it!  It's worth keeping here for sure.  :)

Comment: I don't think that your second example fixes the problem.  The domain there is not really the disk but rather the disk with the line segment $\{r\in [0,1) , \theta = \pi\}$ deleted, and the solution $u$ is really the imaginary part of the holomorphic map $z \mapsto \sqrt{z}$ with the usual branch cut obtained by deleting the same line segment.

Comment: Fair point... but if I changed the argument to $0 \le \theta <2\pi$, the discontinuity disappears and becomes a derivative discontinuity. This removes the issue with the branch cut