# Equivalent norm in $H^{4}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Assume $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ is an open bounded smooth domain. I know that the following function defines a norm on $H^{2}(\Omega)$:

$$\| \cdot \|^{2}_{H^{2}} := \| \cdot \|^{2} + \| \Delta \cdot \|^{2} $$ where $\| \cdot \|$ denotes the $L^{2}$ norm.

Is it true that the following defines an equivalent norm on $H^{4}(\Omega)$?

$$\| \cdot \|^{2}_{H^{4}} := \| \cdot \|^{2}_{H^{2}} + \| \Delta \cdot \|^{2}_{H^{2}} $$

Comment: Your first stated result is not true in general Lipschitz domains.  There are functions $u \in H^1$ of such domains that satisfy $\Delta u = f$ for $f$ smooth and bounded, but $u \notin H^2$.  You need to promote the regularity of the boundary for either of these to possibly hold.

Comment: @Glitch Yes sorry it should be a smooth boundary, I have fixed it now.

Comment: With a smooth boundary, then there is a hope of having some equivalent norm like what you've stated, provided that you restrict the boundary data in some way.  Once more, your initial result is not quite right in general.  See [this post on this site.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4339198/do-u-in-h1-omega-and-delta-u-in-l2-omega-imply-u-in-h2-omega/)